# I want to convert a double array to one element of a cell array in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to convert a double array to one element of a cell array in matlab. How can I do this?
for example a double array like
 [5 3 4 2 1]
must be converted to 
{[5 3 4 2 1]}

Comment: A cell array is represented by `{ }` , not `[ ]`. For your case, it seems that you want to convert a double array `[5 3 4 2 1]` to this  cell array `{[5 3 4 2 1]}`

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html

Comment: In making the clarification edit as suggested by @Sardar, you answered your own question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question is not very clear. I guess this is what you want:

```
a = 5:-1:1; % your double array
myCell = {a}; % put an array into a cell

myCell{1}

ans =

     5     4     3     2     1
```